# Получение части строки, найденой через регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Не могу никак написать регулярку для обычного текста. Другие методы поиска по тексту рассматривать не буду. Так как хочу изучить именно этот метод.
Текст:

```
Пользователь: ФИО - Иванов Иван Иванович
организация - ОАО "Мороженка"
здание - 111
комната - 111
телефон - 1-11-11
Другое
ПК № - 4550
на улице: 111,111,111.
Дата и время - 11:22 12.12.2012.
```

Нужно найти номер ПК (`4550`). Я как бы нашел строку `ПК № - 1017` регуляркой

```
/(ПК № - )[0-9]{1,11}/g
```

А сам номер ПК не могу вытащить.

Comment: Скобки переставьте https://regex101.com/r/qO3oR8/1

Answer (score 2):

Захватывающую подмаску надо сместить на цифры:

```
/ПК № - ([0-9]{1,11})/g
        ^           ^
```

Как мне кажется, количество цифр после `ПК № -` необязательно ограничивать одиннадцатью. Можно и `+` использовать. Но это уже по усмотрению.

Предлагаю такой код:

```js
var re = /ПК\s+№\s+-\s+([0-9]+)/g; 
var str = 'Пользователь: ФИО - Иванов Иван Иванович\nорганизация - ОАО "Мороженка"\nздание - 111\nкомната - 111\nтелефон - 1-11-11\nДругое\nПК № - 4550\nна улице: 111,111,111.\nДата и время - 11:22 12.12.2012.';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[1];  // текст, захваченный подмаской №1
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Регулярное выражение ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/jC3lL4/1)):

- `ПК\s+№\s+-\s+` - тут `\s+` находит любые пробелы, 1 и более раз
- `([0-9]+)` - в захватывающую подмаску №1 помещаются 1 и более цифр

**Если пробелы необязательны, т.е. если их может не быть, замените `\s+` на `\s*`.** Квантификатор `*` означает *0 и более*.

Comment: я бы добавил \s+? ибо не факт что там будут пробелы.

Comment: Тогда уж `\s*`.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, `\s+?` - найдет хотя бы один пробел, но если пробела нет, это выражение не подходит

Comment: /ПК\s+№\s+-\s+([0-9]+)/g Подошло идеально. Пробелы полюбому будут так это формируется из php формы.

Comment: Не за что. Пожалуйста, примите ответ, если он решает Вашу проблему (см. [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).